# Last names in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, listbox

The language is C#. I have a five directories named "a e", "b d", "c c", "d b", and "e a". They appear in a listbox in alphabetical order because I wrote the following code:

```
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\mainFolder\");
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
        }
```

I want them to appear not in the alphabetical order of the first half of their names, but in the alphabetical order of the second half of their names. Their names may change in the future and I need them to remain in the alphabetical order of the second half of their names even after that, but not to worry, I have controls set in place that always assures that they only ever have two halves separated by a single space, (the only space allowed in the name.) I researched MSDN and came to the conclusion that I'd probably need [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx), but that requires a string being split into an array of string parts. How would I use the array I already have with it to achieve the results I just described? Would I need to somehow put my first array inside the new array, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq's `OrderyBy` like this

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\mainFolder\");
foreach (string dir in dirs.OrderBy(p => p.Split(' ')[1]))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
}
```

Note this will throw an exception if the split doesn't result in at least two items (meaning there was no space).  Alternatively you can use `p.Split(new [] { ' ' }, 2)` which will split on the first space only in case the second half could contain spaces you want to consider in the ordering.

Comment: Actually, this works perfectly, accepted, and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use List and sort using custom comparator.

```
var dirs = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\mainFolder\"));

dirs.Sort((x, y) => {
    var lhs = x.Split(' ');
    var rhs = y.Split(' ');

    return lhs.LastOrDefault().CompareTo(rhs.LastOrDefault());

});

foreach(var dir in dirs){
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
}
```

Here you can see I'm sorting list using custom comparator which is sorting list based on last part of name (if exists). It will work perfectly fine regardless of if name is separated by space or not, in order words independent of indexes.